# How to Pass data from node js to vue 3 when using ssr

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, vuejs3

I'm building a website using vue.js 3 and I want to use server-side rendering. I want to also be able to pass data from my fastify (or express) server to vue.js 3. Is there any way I can do this (I have seen something called express-vue: [github link](https://github.com/express-vue/express-vue) but it is for vue 2 and isn't official so I don't know if it is good or not)? And also can you include client side hydration because I have seen examples like https://github.com/moduslabs/vue3-example-ssr but it doesn't include client-side hydration and If this is not possible I will just use ejs but I would prefer vue 3. Could you please give me an example or template I cloud use? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a context object into `renderToString`

```
const context = { data: 'Hello world' } // Data you want to share
const html = renderToString(App, context)
```

This object can be accessed in Vue components using `useSSRContext`

```
setup() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        const context = useSSRContext()
        console.log(context.data) // Hello world
    }
}
```

Unlike Vue 2 where you need to add `data-server-rendered="true"` to your `<div id="app">`, client side hydration happens automatically in Vue 3 when you use `createSSRApp` instead of `createApp` on the browser.

---

To pass the object in the browser, you need to write it to a window variable in your `<head>` when returning the result from the server

```
const html = renderToString(App, context)

res.send(`
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>window.context = ${JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(context))}</script>
    </head>
        <body><div id="app">${html}</div></body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </html>
`)
```